# Modem without bridge mode and personal router

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, modem

I recently switched ISPs and received a new modem.
Back with my old ISP, I had three public IPs and my modem was able to switch to bridge mode. My previous setup was like this.

- Modem -> Router (Primary / 192.168.1.1) -> Personal Network
- Modem -> Router (Secondary / 192.168.2.1) -> Guests etc.

Both routers had two different public IPs and thus I was fairly certain that these were indeed two separate networks where no device could see a device from the other router etc.

Now with my new modem, each router gets a 192.168.0.x IP.

I'm still able to configure my routers with 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.2.1 as their respective subnet but now I'm wondering if that setup still works the way I want it.

I would just like to have two networks which are separated on a hardware level. I know I can enable a guest wifi on my primary router but that's not what I want to do.

Can anybody tell me, if two separate router still make sense if my modem does not have a bridge mode?

Side question: I also configured two static routes on my modem that forward traffic to my two routers. 192.168.1.0 to my primary router and 192.168.2.0 to my secondary router.

The description says:

Expert users can use static routes to operate an additional router on the Internet-Box. To enable the Internet-Box to recognize the network of the additional router, a static route must be entered the first time. This ensures that the data traffic is forwarded to the additional network.

However, I just noticed that setting recently and before that everything was working just fine. Do I even need these static routes? It seems like nothing changed after setting them.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you have routes to forward traffic between networks, then what exactly is "separation at hardware level" giving you? (Probably nothing.)

Comment: @grawity hm i don’t know tbh, networking is my weak spot. i just read the description of the function and thought, yeah that sounds like what i want and then i put it in. but without multiple routers there wouldn’t be static routes to implement, or not? i’m not sure what you’re saying, sorry.